# What is the simplest way to check to see if webmin is installed?

Tags: software-installation, webmin

I dug up an old server that is only running CLI, and can't seem to remember if Webmin was installed on the machine or not. I normally implement it on all machines, but it doesn't seem like it's working on this one.

Is there a quick command to check to see if it's installed or a directory that Webmin has to exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be in /usr/share/webmin

so try **`ls /usr/share/`**  or try **`whereis webmin`**

Alternately try  **`sudo dpkg --get-selections`** , to list all packages.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to see if its installed would be to launch a borwser and try loading up the web interface.

https://domain.com:10000

Comment: FWIW, this won't check if it's installed. This test will only check if it's running and listening on it's default port (10000). It may be installed and not running or listening on an alternate port.